# Android ListActivity different title and activity name

Tags: android, listactivity

I'd like to show the user a list of different available activities in my app, but I want the names to be explicit such as "Accelerometer Control", or "Line Follower". Right now the activities are stored in a `String` array, these activity names are what are shown AND called. I'd like to show "Line Follower" and call the "LineFollower" activity (without space). I haven't found any examples doing that.

Here's ListActivity that should show the available activities:

```
public class ActivityList extends ListActivity {
    // here I'd like to have "Accelerometer Control", "Touch Control"...
    String[] activities = new String[] {"AccelerometerControl", "TouchControl", "ArrowControl", "LineFollower", "Piano", "SendData", "LEDEqualizer", "Program"};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activities));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String activity = activities[position];

        try
        {
            Class<?> activityClass = Class.forName("com.bluetooth." + activity);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityList.this, activityClass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the activities like you would normally want to appear in the list and when it's time to start them simply remove the empty spaces between the names:

```
String[] activities = new String[] {"Accelerometer Control", "Touch Control", "Arrow Control", "Line Follower", "Piano", "Send Data", "LED Equalizer", "Program"};

// ...
String activity = activities[position];
activity = activity.replace(" ", "");
try {
    Class<?> activityClass = Class.forName("com.bluetooth." + activity);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityList.this, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setTitle by itself, like this in those activites where u want:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);      
this.setTitle("myclass2");
```